# Turn off function on mouseoff and mouseup

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, mouseup

I have implemented my own scrolling, in a ticker with Jquery because the normal scrolling doesn't work too well when there's already css animation involved. 
What I want to have happen is when you click and drag on the controller, which is a div that contains the ticker, the ticker moves. When you release the mouse button, it stops. No problem there. The problem comes in, when I don't release the mouse button, but I do take the mouse off of the controller. When this happens track_mouse_pos doesn't stop. So clicked or not when I put my mouse back on the controller I am scrolling.

```
$("#controller").mousedown(function (event) {
    var start_x = event.clientX;
    var start_y = event.clientY;
    $("#controller").on('mousemove', {start_x: start_x}, track_mouse_pos);
});

$("#controller").mouseup(function () {
    $("#controller").off('mousemove', track_mouse_pos);
});
```

How can I turn off `('mousemove', track_mouse_pos);`? Is it ok to just have a `.mouseup` and `.mouseoff` line doing the same thing?

Comment: Maybe the mouseenter / mouseleave events will do the trick?

http://api.jquery.com/category/events/mouse-events/

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the mouse button pressed in the "track_mouse_pos" function.

```
function track_mouse_pos(e){
  if(e.which!=1) {$("#controller").trigger('mouseup');return}
...
}
```